# Unexpected fault on ReliableSession in NetTcpBinding (WCF)

Tags: c#, wcf, fault, reliablesession

I have a client server application. My scenario:

- .Net Framework 4.6.1
- Quad Core i7 machine with hyperthreading enabled
- Server CPU load from 20 - 70 %
- Network load < 5% (GBit NIC)
- 100 users
- 30 services (some administrative ones, some generic ones per datatype) running and each user is connected to all services
- NetTcpBinding (compression enabled)
- ReliableSession enabled
- each second I do trigger (server side) an update notification and all clients load from the server approx. 100 kB
- additionally a heartbeat is running (for testing 15 seconds interval) which simply returns the server time in UTC

Sometimes the WCF connections change to faulted state. Usually when this happens the server has no network upstream at all. I did write a memory dump and was able to see that lots of WCF threads were waiting for some `WaitQueue`. The call stack is:

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransmissionStrategy.WaitQueueAdder.Wait(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransmissionStrategy.InternalAdd(Message message, Boolean isLast, TimeSpan timeout, Object state, MessageAttemptInfo& attemptInfo)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableOutputConnection.InternalAddMessage(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, Object state, Boolean isLast)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReliableDuplexSessionChannel.OnSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DuplexChannel.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Send(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

I did tweak the settings and it seems that the situation is eased - Now there are faulting less clients. My settings:

- ReliableSession.InactivityTimeout: 01:30:00
- ReliableSession.Enabled: True
- ReliableSession.Ordered: False
- ReliableSession.FlowControlEnabled: False
- ReliableSession.MaxTransferWindowSize: 4096
- ReliableSession.MaxPendingChannels: 16384
- MaxReceivedMessageSize: 1073741824
- ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength: 8388608
- ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength: 1073741824

I am stuck. Why do all calls try to wait for some `WaitQueue` in the `TransmissionStrategy`? I do not care about messages being sent out of order (I do take care of that myself). I was already thinking about disabling reliable messaging but the application is used in a company network worldwide. I need to know that my messages were delivered.

Any ideas how to teach WCF to just send the messages and do not care about anything else?

**EDIT**

The values for service throttling are set to `Int32.MaxValue`.

I did also try to set `MaxConnections` and `ListenBackLog` (on `NetTcpBinding`) to their maximum values. It did not change anything - as far as I can tell.

**EDIT 2**

Checking the WCF Traces it tells me (German message, therefore a rough translation) that there is no available space in the reliable messaging transfer window - and then all I get are Timeouts because no more messages are sent.

Whats going on there? Is it possible that the reliable messaging confuses itself?

Comment: Turning on trace should show when a channel faults, and why. I think its better to give trace a chance before tinkering with a production app

Comment: @Menahem please check **Edit 2**

Comment: It looks like thwres a deeper problem, if the 4096 transfer window is nit enough. Its seems nessages are not being acknowledged. Are the client and server on the same network? If so reliable sessions is not required. If not maybe the acks are getting dropped

Comment: @Menahem in my testing environment most of them are on the same switch - however in production it is a world wide company network

Comment: And the issue is on the testing net?

Comment: @Menahem I did set up this testing environment because I have this behavior in production

Comment: And this issue reproduces in the test env?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186653/discussion-between-menahem-and-toatwork).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short:

It turns out that my WCF settings are just fine.

The ThreadPool is the limiting factor. In high traffic (and therefore high load) situations I do generate to much messages which have to be sent to the clients. Those are queued up as there are not enough worker threads to send the messages. At some point the queue is full - and there you are.

For more details check this [question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15840313/2243584) from Russ Bishop.

Interesting detail: This did even decrease the CPU load in high traffic situations. From spiking crazy between 30 and 80 percent to a(n) (almost) steady value around 30 percent. I can only assume that is is because of threadpool thread generation and cleanup.

**EDIT**

I did the following:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(1000, 500)
```

That values might be like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut - but it works.

Comment: Thank you for the update ! But what did you do to solve the problem ?

Comment: Also, if the server is calling clients only as a notification , it should not take long to handle, and thus will not drain the server`s resources. it seems to me that remote calls should be as short as possible

Comment: @Menahem To further clarify: when a dataobject is modified an update notification is sent to the clients which then load the new version of the object. If there were many updates it seems that the worker threads were not able to keep pace...

Answer (score 2):

The wait queue can be related to wcf built in throttling behavior https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/servicethrottling
The best way to troubleshoot is to enable wcf tracing 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/servicethrottling
And know exactly what is the root cause

Comment: Nope. I did set all 3 of them to `Int.MaxValue`

Comment: Tracing just tells me that the reliable transfer window is full (see my updated question). Any further ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Do you use connectionManagement to set  maxconnection of your client?(If your session is duplex)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/network/connectionmanagement-element-network-settings

Your MaxPendingChannels is  set to 16384, which will make too many client wait in the queue, if the server couldn't deal with the clients  in time, the channel may turn to fault state.

FlowControlEnabled means whether to continue sending message to server side when the server has no space left to save the message. You had better set it to true.

InactivityTimeout means whether to close the session when there is no message exchange  within a certain period of time. You had better set it to a suitable value.

In addition , have you set your binding's timeout?

```
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding  closeTimeout="" openTimeout="" receiveTimeout="" sendTimeout="" ></binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
```

Comment: I do use default values except for the receive timeout.